# Change the over scroll color in cordova iOS

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there a way t change the overscroll color? By default it's gray.

I know i can disable it with

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

But i don't want that.

I tried to give the html tag a background color of black, but this does not work.

Any help much appreciated!